# fail2ban distinguish between results for same ip

Tags: linux, fail2ban

I need to implement fail2ban in order to secure a server. I would like to scan the logs and ban hosts that generate lots of 404 messages.

The problem I have, is that there may be a number of clients behind a certain NAT'd IP, and I need to distiguish between them. Each client is requesting a different URL in the following format:

```
https://server.example.com/path/<uniqueid>/<mac_address>
```

I would like to run fail2ban so it considers the unique ID in the regex rather than just looking at the number of 404 errors per IP.

I have developed the following regex which seems to trap the needed events:

```
(?P<host>(\d{1,3}.){4})\ -\ -\ \[\d{1,2}\/\w+\/\d{4}[\:\d{2}]+\ \+\d{4}\] "GET \/path\/(?P<unique_id>.+)\/.+HTTP\/\d.\d" ".+" ".+" 404.+
```

This should match:

```
1.1.1.11 - - [29/Aug/2018:01:27:45 +0100] "GET /path/3B44444444483/ddddee37D4.cfg HTTP/1.1" "somestring" "otherstring" 404 - 2005 5 0.117
```

And this should match but be considered a different instance than the above:

```
1.1.1.11 - - [29/Aug/2018:01:27:45 +0100] "GET /path/3B46666444483/ddddee37D4.cfg HTTP/1.1" "somestring" "otherstring" 404 - 2005 5 0.117
```

Comment: *"The problem I have, is that there may be a number of clients behind a certain NAT'd IP, and I need to distiguish between them"* **Note:** that  in the end fail2ban blocks ip-addresses,  not specific clients and a single bad client behind the NAT router will still result in all other well-behaved clients getting blocked regardless...

Comment: Yes, this is fine. If a client generates enough 404's to block the IP, then it will definitely be nefarious and OK to block the entire IP.

Answer (score 0):

Using this configuration your server is consuming more CPU looking for 404 responses in logs that any security benefit or CPU benefit of not serving 404 response for X IP.

If you don't like seeing these responses, don't create log entries for them.